# How "site" can be input for the viewer? What is "site" in Eclipse API?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How "site" can be input for the viewer? What is "site" in Eclipse API?

I found the following code in `SampleView`:

```
viewer.setInput(getViewSite());
```

where `viewer` is of type `TableViewer`.

So, here is where I usually assign a model to the view. But here some "site" is assigned.

Is "site" the notion of "model" in Eclipse API?

Simultaneously it is said about `IWorkbenchPartSite` that it is @noimplement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you mean the `SampleView` generated by the Eclipse examples. In this particular case the view content provider does not actually look at the value passed to `setInput` so any value would be OK here. I just tested it with `setInput(this)` and it still works.

In general each view has a `IViewSite` which provides various services but is nothing to do with the view model, its use here is rather misleading.

Normally the value to `setInput` would be the root of your view model and would be an object that you create.